# How to know in what environment the code runs?

Tags: ruby, haml, middleman

In the `layout` file of `haml` I would like to determine whether we are in our development and build environments. We're using Middleman.

I would like to do something like this:

```
- if environment == 'development'
    / Development Code
    = javascript_include_tag "Dev.js"
```

I tried to access Ruby's environment variable, as well as define a custom variable in the `config.rb` file with no success.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You’ve almost got it right – you need to check against a symbol rather than a string:

```
- if environment == :development
    / Development Code
    = javascript_include_tag "Dev.js"
```

Middleman also adds the [`development?` and `build?` methods](https://github.com/middleman/middleman/blob/v3.0.6/middleman-core/lib/middleman-core/application.rb#L200-206) which may be easier to use:

```
- if development?
    / Development Code
    = javascript_include_tag "Dev.js"
```

This works with ERB too:

```
<% if development? %>
<!-- Development Code -->
<%= javascript_include_tag "Dev.js" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if possible, you should separate the logic from the data. Determine your environment in your controller, and toggle the data being sent to the view (HAML layout file).

Typically you'd set a flag in your environment variables and access it in your code from `ENV`. For instance, Sinatra makes the development/test/production setting available inside the code using their `RACK_ENV` symbol:

```
:environment - configuration/deployment environment A symbol
specifying the deployment environment; typically set to one of
:development, :test, or :production. The :environment defaults to the
value of the RACK_ENV environment variable (ENV['RACK_ENV']), or
:development when no RACK_ENV environment variable is set.

The environment can be set explicitly:

set :environment, :production
```

If you have to roll your own, that's a good way to go about it.

Answer (score -1):

Use the :environment symbol that middleman creates by default:
http://rubydoc.info/github/middleman/middleman/Middleman/Application#environment-instance_method

combined with haml - you can do something like:

```
= javascript_include_tag "Dev.js" unless :environment == "developement"
```

note that middlemans build process changes the :environment value to "build"

you can also use developement? to test whether you're on dev or not: http://rubydoc.info/github/middleman/middleman/Middleman/Application#development%3F-instance_method

All the above applies to middleman 3.0.6 and might not work on lesser versions (won't work on 2.x for sure)